# Need some Python datetime magic

Tags: python, datetime

Hey all. I don't think this should be very complicated but I just can't get it. I have a list of `datetime` objects starting at a certain date and ending at one. Some days can be skipped. I can print them out like this:

```
for entry in dates:
    print entry
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
2010-11-29 10:00:00.0
2010-12-30 10:00:00.0 
2010-12-01 10:00:00.0 # Note that December 3rd has been skipped
...
2010-12-07 10:00:00.0
```

What I'd like to do is get an output like this:

```
Day 1: ok
Day 2: ok
Day 3: skipped
Day 4: ok
...
Day 10: ok
```

Could anybody help me out with some common sense here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your example output is a bit wrong. It jumps from Nov 29 (11-29) to Dec 30 (12-30) then back to Dec 1 (12-01). Although I think we understand what you mean!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to do this by converting your `datetime`s to `date`s. Rather than try to iterate over the dates themselves, we take a `timedelta` of the last date and the first date (this requires your dates to be sorted, I added a `sorted` call in case they aren't). Then we see if the first date plus the number of days is in your original set for each day in the range:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dts = [datetime(2010, 11, 29, 10, 0, 0), datetime(2010, 11, 30, 10, 0, 0),
       datetime(2010, 12, 4, 10, 0, 0)]
dates = sorted(d.date() for d in dts)

for d in range((dates[-1] - dates[0]).days + 1):
    st = 'ok' if dates[0] + timedelta(days=d) in dates else 'skipped'
    print 'Day %d: %s' % (d + 1, st)
```

Output:

```
Day 1: ok
Day 2: ok
Day 3: skipped
Day 4: skipped
Day 5: skipped
Day 6: ok
```

Note: I created my own example here because I'm not sure the example you used actually makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

use the "rrule" module from the dateutil package, found at http://labix.org/python-dateutil

```
import datetime
from dateutil import rrule

dates = (datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 29),
         datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 30),
         datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 2))

all_dates = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, count=5, 
                 dtstart=datetime.datetime(2010, 11,29)))

for (i, date) in enumerate(all_dates):
    if date in dates:
        status = "ok"
    else:
        status = "skipped"

    print "Day %s: %s" % (i+1, status)
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the `rrule` module.  Now I can figure out when Easter is.

Comment: +1, pretty cool idea, I also didn't know about `rrule`, although I'm not sure I would want to install a new package just to solve this problem.